# Facebook Payment API not returning Payment information only created_time

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-payments

The url at `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/${payment_id}` is not returning any Payment information for Test User payments beyond created_time.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/payment

It says it suppose to return a large amount of data related to a payment and presumably at a minimum the status so one can verify the status of a payment.

1. What is the expected behavior for Test User payment and live Payments?
2. Are you experiencing the same behavior?

Comment: Almost all API endpoints only return a few core fields by default - everything else you want, you need to explicitly ask for, using the `fields` parameter. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api